# Twitter bootstrap scrollspy - disable on smooth scroll?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

We are using the twitter bootstrap scrollspy on a sidebar ul/il list, this works great.
We do however also use smooth scrolling when clicking the links in the sidebar.
This causes the scrollspy to highlight each and every element that comes into view, as it should in normal cases.

But when the scrolling is triggered by a click on the links in the side nav, the users most likely don't expect the menu to animate as the scrolling occurs.
Is there any way to temporarily disable the scrollspy while the animated scroll is running, and then reenable it once scrolling is complete?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `data-spy` attribute temporarily (assuming you are using `data-`)?

Comment: I'm using javascript to activate it

Comment: In that case, try setting a class as data-target, remove the class as the scrolling animation is running, and re-insert the class after animation is done? `$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active' });`

Comment: that works like a charm.. make an answer of it and Ill mark it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By setting a class as the target of `scrollspy` you can dynamically stop/resume `scrollspy` operation.

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active' });
```

Now one will just need to add or remove the `.spy-active` class on the navigation.

Comment: The issue is when reactivating (readding the class), scrollSpy does not refresh the current active class.

Comment: @dude, you can re-enable the class by doing something with your `.animate`'s event in the `complete` callback with something like: `complete: function() { $("#nav").addClass("active-spy"); $(event.target.parentNode).addClass("active"); }`. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o92wrpg8/2/

Answer (score 0):

add the following to the top of your local javascript...

```
$.fn.scrollspy.Constructor.prototype.destroy = function(){
    this.$element.off('scroll.bs.scroll-spy.data-api');
    this.$body.removeData('bs.scrollspy');
    return this.$body;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works, and in particular how unhooking only the `scroll.bs.scroll-spy.data-api` event (which I have never heard of) automagically unhooks all the other scrollspy events too?

Comment: By perusing the actual ScrollSpy plugin code at **[link](https://gist.github.com/kirov/9482666)** 
You can see that there is only one event attached to the scrollspy element. the 'scroll.bs.scroll-spy.data-api' event.